# Is there a way I can revert panda lib to more simpler python code

Tags: python, function, cluster-computing, k-means

everyone. I'm new to python and not really familiar with a lot of libraries. I'm doing an assignment which is to create a kmean cluster and did a research regarding that and came across this def

```
def calc_centroids(clusters, X):
    new_centroids = []
    new_df = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(X), pd.DataFrame(clusters, columns=['cluster'])],
                      axis=1)
    for c in set(new_df['cluster']):
        current_cluster = new_df[new_df['cluster'] == c][new_df.columns[:-1]]
        cluster_mean = current_cluster.mean(axis=0)
        new_centroids.append(cluster_mean)
    return new_centroids
```

I'm planning to incorporate this definition into my program. The website I got it from briefly give insight to what the function is for, but isn't really helpful. Like I said, I'm not really familiar with panada lib and was wondering if anyone could help me rewrite the above definition into much simpler python codes. It would be really appreciative if anyone can help.

Comment: This isn't a code rewriting forum, so this question is inappropriate. At most, we can provide you with info on how to solve your problem. For example, `pd.concat` joins the arguments given into a new dataframe (think table). The loop loops around each unique cluster (due to `set`), selects the cluster column, calculates its mean, and adds that value to `new_centroid`. With this info, try to translate the snippet to simpler python code.

Comment: Hey, that's totally understandable, thanks for some pointers. However, how can I convert the data structure into a frame or do I even need to use a frame?

Comment: That function converts X and clusters into a single dataframe, they don't have to be beforehand. They also should have the same length. It's not necessary to use pandas, only convenient. The alternative is to use two lists and two loops, one to iterate through the unique clusters and a second to select the appropriate terms and calculate their mean.

Comment: I got it!!! Got it working. Thank you so much